# How to import `npm` module in angular application that exports function and namespace with types?

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings, commonjs

I have installed the npm package https://github.com/alferov/array-to-tree/

```
npm install array-to-tree --save
```

In its index.d.ts file there are declarations of function and namespace:

```
export = arrayToTree;

declare function arrayToTree<T>(data: T[], options?: Partial<arrayToTree.Options>): Array<arrayToTree.Tree<T>>;

declare namespace arrayToTree {
    interface Options {
        childrenProperty: string;
        parentProperty: string;
        customID: string;
        rootID: string;
    }

    type Tree<T> = T & {
        children?: Array<Tree<T>>;
    };
}
```

I tried to import it in my angular application in such way:

```
import * as arrayToTree from 'array-to-tree';
```

But I got compilation error:

*error TS2307: Cannot find module 'arrayToTree'.*

I also tried to import using the CommonJS-style:

```
import arrayToTree = require('array-to-tree');
```

and got error from code editor:

*TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using `'import * as ns from "mod"'`, `'import {a} from "mod"'` or `'import d from "mod"'` instead.*

I tried all the proposed variants but didin't solve the problem.

I thought that problem may be related with package.json file in npm-package because It didn't have option  `"typings": "index.d.ts"`. But I tried to add this option and got no result.

I suppose that problem is with importing namespace together with function.
Or may be problem is with compatibility Typescript version and index.d.ts file format ? I use Typescript 3.2.2.

What am I doing wrong ?

Update:
I make example on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehjdfy

There is error in console.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the libary:

`import * as arrayToTree from 'array-to-tree'` works fine.

*node ./node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js*

```
> import * as arrayToTree from 'array-to-tree'
{}
> arrayToTree.toString()
'function arrayToTree(data, options) {\n  options = Object.assign(\n    {\n      parentProperty: \'parent_id\',\n      childrenProperty: \'children\',\n      customID: \'id\',\n      rootID: \'0\'\n    },\n    options\n  );\n\n  if (!Array.isArray(data)) {\n    throw new TypeError(\'Expected an array but got an invalid argument\');\n  }\n\n  var grouped = groupByParents(deepClone(data), options);\n  return createTree(\n    grouped,\n    grouped[options.rootID],\n    options.customID,\n    options.childrenProperty\n  );\n}'
```

Comment: You test it in javascript ?
I use it in angular app in Typescript. May be problem is with angular or ts-compiler config ? It can't find nessasary file ?

Comment: No, I checked it in TypeScript, notice that `node ./node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js` starts TypeScript Interpreter. Its like installing ts-node globally https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I see. And what TS version did you use ? If it is one of the latest versions, I think that problem is with angular or ts config files...

Comment: Could you please select an answer? I suggest you create a new post for your new question.

Comment: Question is the same - problem with import.
I updated the post with example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehjdfy